# Applet Choice does not call Item state change method each time I change the item of Choice(list) why?

Tags: java, swing, applet

Code: Each time I change item(list item /choice) of list browser it calls `itemStateChanged()` and call `repaint()`. But this is not same in the case of os list on change its item it does not call `itemStateChanged()` don't know why but lister is attached to both of them.

```
 import java.applet.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

    public class AppletList extends Applet implements ItemListener {
        String msg = "";
        Choice browser, os;

        public void init() {
            setForeground(Color.red);
            browser=new Choice();
            os=new Choice();

            browser.addItem("Explorer");
            browser.addItem("Chrome");
            browser.addItem("Mozilla");

            os.addItem("Windows");
            os.addItem("Mac");

            add(browser);
            add(os);
            os.addItemListener(this);
            browser.addItemListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            repaint();

        }
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            msg="Browser : ";
            msg+=browser.getSelectedItem();
            g.drawString(msg, 6,120);

            msg="OS :+ ";
            msg+=os.getSelectedItem();
            g.drawString(msg, 6, 140);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Really?  Applet and AWT was superseded by Swing 15+ years ago. You will find better support if you actually make use of the Swing library. Applets are also problematic at the best of time, you'd be better off using a `JFrame` as you top level container. Having said that, you should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers (like `Applet` and `JFrame`) and instead use something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, although in your case, I'd recommend using `JLabel`s

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Java and operating system are you using? Your applet is working fine on my laptop (with Java 8 and Windows 8.1).

Following (some of) the suggestions of [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) to switch to Swing and use `JLabel`s, you could give this code a try (I agree that using Swing and regular components is better, and perhaps it even solves the issue on your machine):

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class AppletListSwing extends Applet implements ItemListener {
    private JComboBox<String> browserComboBox;
    private JComboBox<String> osComboBox;
    private JLabel browserLabel;
    private JLabel osLabel;

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Create the control panel.
        final JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();

        browserComboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Explorer", "Chrome", "Mozilla"});
        osComboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Windows", "Mac"});
        browserComboBox.setForeground(Color.RED);
        osComboBox.setForeground(Color.RED);

        controlPanel.add(browserComboBox);
        controlPanel.add(osComboBox);
        add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        browserComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        osComboBox.addItemListener(this);

        // Create the display panel.
        final JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
        displayPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(28, 28, 28, 28));
        displayPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(displayPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        browserLabel = new JLabel();
        osLabel = new JLabel();
        browserLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        osLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);

        displayPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 42)));
        displayPanel.add(browserLabel);
        displayPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 6)));
        displayPanel.add(osLabel);

        add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        updateDisplayPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        updateDisplayPanel();
    }

    private void updateDisplayPanel() {
        browserLabel.setText("Browser : " + browserComboBox.getSelectedItem());
        osLabel.setText("OS :+ " + osComboBox.getSelectedItem());
    }
}
```